# Connecting Morphism of Exact Triangle of Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, morphism

I am self-studying topology with only background in physics. I follow [this lecture notes](https://people.sissa.it/%7Ebruzzo/notes/IATG/notes.pdf). On page 4, proposition 1.4 says:

> **Proposition**: Let $M^{\prime}$, $M$, and $M^{\prime\prime}$ be [differential $R$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+module), with differential morphisms $d^{\prime}:M^{\prime}\rightarrow M^{\prime}$, $d:M\rightarrow M$, and $d^{\prime\prime}: M^{\prime\prime}\rightarrow M^{\prime\prime}$, such that $$d^{\prime}\circ d^{\prime}=d\circ d=d^{\prime\prime}\circ d^{\prime\prime}=0.$$
> Let the following diagram $$0\xrightarrow{}M^{\prime}\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow}M\overset{p}{\twoheadrightarrow}M^{\prime\prime}\xrightarrow{}0$$
> be a short exact sequence, and $H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})$, $H(M,d)$, and $H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})$ the cohomology groups, respectively. Then, there exists a morphism $\delta:H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})\rightarrow H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})$ such that the following diagram $$\require{AMScd}
> \require{cancel}
> \def\diagdownarrow#1{\smash{
>   \raise.6em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1}
>   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}
> }}
> \begin{CD}
> && H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})\\
> & \diagdownarrow{\delta} @VV H(i) V \\
> H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime}) @<< H(p)< H(M,d)
> \end{CD}$$
> is exact.

***My question is about its proof***:

To begin with, we can pick up an element $[m^{\prime\prime}]\in H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})$, where $m^{\prime\prime}$ is a cocycle in $M^{\prime\prime}$. Since $p$ is surjective, there exists an element $m\in M$ such that $p(m)=m^{\prime\prime}$. Then, it follows that $$p\circ d(m)=d^{\prime\prime}\circ p(m)=0.$$

This means $d(m)\in\ker(p)=\mathrm{im}(i)$, i.e there exists $m^{\prime}\in M^{\prime}$ such that $d(m)=i(m^{\prime})$. Then, one finds $$i\circ d^{\prime}(m^{\prime})=d\circ i(m^{\prime})=d\circ d(m)=0.$$

But since $i$ is injective, the above identity means $d^{\prime}(m^{\prime})=0$. i.e $m^{\prime}$ is a cocycle in $M^{\prime}$.

Now, to show that $m^{\prime}$ defines a morphism $H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})\rightarrow H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})$, I must first show that for each $[m^{\prime\prime}]\in H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})$, there exists at most one $[m^{\prime}]\in H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})$. But this isn't so obvious to me because the preimage of $p(m)$ isn't unique.

**So my question is how to prove that the morphism** $$\delta:H(M^{\prime\prime},d^{\prime\prime})\rightarrow H(M^{\prime},d^{\prime})$$

**exists**?

Answer (score 1):

Given $[m''] \in H(M'', d'')$, the definition of $\delta([m''])$ involves making two choices: we chose a representative element in $M''$ of the cohomology class $[m'']$, and we chose a pullback $m$ of $m''$. To see that it is well defined we have to make sure that our class $[m']$ is independent of these choices.

For the latter say we have $m_1, m_2$ with $p(m_1) = p(m_2) = m''$, and $m_1', m_2' \in M'$ with $i(m_1') = d(m_1), i(m_2') = d(m_2)$. Then $p(m_1 - m_2) = p(m_1) - p(m_2) = 0$ so $m_1 - m_2 = i(m')$. Now $i(d'(m')) = d(i(m')) = d(m_1 - m_2) = d(m_1) - d(m_2) = i(m_1') - i(m_2') = i(m_1' - m_2')$, so $d'(m') = m_1' - m_2'$ as $i$ is injective. Then $[m_1' - m_2'] = 0$ so $[m_1'] = [m_2']$ and hence two pullbacks of $m''$ define the same cohomology class in $H(M', d')$.

Now we need to show that $\delta([m''])$ is independent of the choice of representation for our cohomology class. For this take $m_1'', m_2''$ with $[m_1''] = [m_2'']$. We take $m_1, m_2$ with $p(m_1) = m_1''$ and $p(m_2) = m_2''$ and $m_1', m_2'$ with $i(m_1') = d(m_1), i(m_2') = d(m_2)$. Since $[m_1''] = [m_2'']$ we have $m_1'' - m_2'' = d''(m'')$. Take some $m$ with $p(m) = m''$, so that $p(d(m)) = d''(p(m)) = d''(m'') = p(m_1 - m_2)$. Then $p(m_1 - m_2 - d(m)) = 0$ and there exists $m' \in M'$ with $i(m') = m_1 - m_2 - d(m)$. Thus $i(d'(m')) = d(i(m')) = d(m_1 - m_2 - d(m)) = d(m_1) - d(m_2) = i(m_1') - i(m_2')$, so by injectivity $m_1' - m_2' = d'(m')$ and $\delta([m_1'']) = [m_1'] = [m_2'] = \delta([m_2''])$.

We conclude $\delta$ is well defined. It's probably worth mentioning that there's a purely categorical version of this argument coming from applying the snake lemma to a commutative diagram given by stacking one copy of your SES on top of the other to get two rows and then connecting them vertically with the differential maps, if that means anything to you.

Comment: Hi @Elie Thanks for answering my question. But can you tell me why $\delta$ is a homomorphism? In your jargon, $m^{\prime}$ is a pullback of $m^{\prime\prime}$.

Comment: If it isn't clear by pulling back I mean taking an element of the preimage/fiber. $\delta$ is a homomorphism because given two classes $[m_1''], [m_2'']$, if we take $m_1, m_2$ with $p(m_1) = m_1'', p(m_2) = m_2''$ then $p(m_1 + m_2) = m_1'' + m_2''$, and if we take $m_1', m_2'$ with $i(m_1') = \delta(m_1), i(m_2') = \delta(m_2)$, then $i(m_1' + m_2') = \delta(m_1 + m_2)$. Then by definition $\delta([m_1'' + m_2'']) = [m_1' + m_2'] = [m_1'] + [m_2'] = \delta([m_1'']) + \delta([m_2''])$, and hence $\delta$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: First, $m^{\prime\prime}$ is related to an $m$ via $p(m)=m^{\prime\prime}$. Then this $m$ is related to $m^{\prime}$ via $i(m^{\prime})=dm$. It means $\delta$ sends the class of $m^{\prime\prime}$ to something like $(i)^{-1}dp^{-1}$. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: $\delta$ can't be defined by literally composing maps and then taking the cohomology class because $p$ isn't injective (unless $M'$ is trivial.) But since $p$ is surjective we can choose an element in the fiber of $m''$ over $p$, send that element through $d$, and then take its preimage under $i$ (well defined because $i$ is injective). 

This involves making a choice of an element in the preimage of that representative. But it turns out that different choices here will lead to elements in $M'$ that lie in the same cohomology class, as I showed in my post. So $\delta$ is still well defined.

Comment: But it's just a way to relate $m^{\prime\prime}$ to $m^{\prime}$. How to show that $\delta$ is a homomorphism? aka for each $[m^{\prime\prime}]$ one can atmost find only one such $[m^{\prime}]$?

Comment: $\delta$ being a homomorphism would mean that it distributes over addition, i.e that $\delta([m_1''] + [m_2'']) = \delta([m_1'']) + \delta([m_2''])$. What you are asking is why the map $\delta$ is well defined. Given $[m'']$, the construction of $[m']$ was dependent on a choice of representative for the cohomology class $[m'']$ and a choice of an element in the fiber of that representative. I show in my original answer that no matter what you choose, for either choice, you get the same cohomology class.

Comment: No I am not asking you why it is well defined. I am asking you why it is a homomorphism.

Comment: If it's a homomorphism, then for each class $[m^{\prime\prime}]$, under the "map" (so far I can only see that $\delta$ is a way to relate $[m^{\prime\prime}]$ to $[m^{\prime}]$, and don't see why $\delta$ is a map) $\delta$ there's atmost one class $[m^{\prime}]$ such that $\delta([m^{\prime\prime}])=[m^{\prime}]$. I am not asking whether it's independent of the choice of representative $m^{\prime}$.